# How to evenly set column width for a table within a div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been working at this on and off for two days, and I can't figure out how to make this work.

I have a table-based display of charts on the home page of my website. These charts are small and compact. I have it so that when you click on one of the charts, an expanded view pops up with a larger view of charts, also organized as a table. This view is a fixed centered div that covers 80%x80% of the screen, with a table inside. I want this table to fill the inner width of the div and be scrollable. The table has 3 columns, and I want each to be 33.3% wide to evenly space each one.

HTML:

```
<div id="expandedViewContainer">
    <div id="expandedView">
        <table id="expandedViewTable">
            <tr class="expandedViewRow">
                <td class="expandedViewCell">
                    <div class="expandedChart"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="expandedViewCell">
                    <div class="expandedChart"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="expandedViewCell">
                    <div class="expandedChart"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#expandedViewContainer {
    display:none; /*The view is initially hidden*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:999999;
}
#expandedView {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:#ADC4DB;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#expandedViewTable {
    /*I'm expecting this to mean 100% of the inner width of #expandedView,
    but I can't be sure what's happening here*/
    width:100%; 
}
.expandedViewRow {
    height:300px;
}
.expandedViewCell {
    width:33.3px;
}
.expandedChart {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 30px;
}
```

For some reason, the table is extending way past the width of the #expandedView. Some of the charts are very wide. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to set as `width:100%` and what I'm supposed to set as `width:33.3%`.

FYI, I'm using HighCharts to generate the charts, with the .expandedChart's as the containers. I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the width that's being set.

Comment: can you add a JSfiddle ?

Comment: if you set width in css for td's, then you can use : table-layout.fixed; on parent table. it won'nt evenly set width, but it will keep width settled in CSS.